# Elasticsearch bulk request with gzipped data in nodejs

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, aws-lambda, gzip, aws-elasticsearch

We have a lot of records to be indexed in Elasticsearch. For POC, we are running a local Elasticsearch cluster, e.g. `localhost:9200`.

We have turned on the cluster compression support in `config/elasticsearch.yml` but adding `http.compression: true`

When the record size increases, Elasticsearch throws errors

`"statusCode":413,"response":"{\"Message\":\"Request size exceeded 10485760 bytes\"}`

Is there a way to gzip the data which we send in `_bulk` query? Looking for a solution in `node.js` only.

`Elasticsearch.js` doesn't support it at the moment. I've [logged an issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/issues/699) with them.